# Pearson r Interpretation

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Magnitude of a relationship](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15593/magnitude-of-a-relationship)

I have a set of data that has a Pearson correlation of .822 with sig. (1 tailed) of .001.  I am not a statistics person but what exactly does that mean?  Is it a strong linear correlation or not?